# What is the difference between <batch:end /> and <batch:fail /> in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

While going though the spring batch documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html ,

i encountered with these two tags , which are bit confusing .

```
<end on="FAILED" />
<fail on="FAILED" />
```

What is the difference between these two , Can someone clarify this for me .

Comment: the first end the batch job and marks the job completed, the other one end and marks the job as failed.

Comment: So for the second case what should be the return status of the java program ? 0 or >0

Comment: Whatever you like, the fact that a batch job failed doesn't mean the program failed, nor does it have to be part of a standalone program.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for in the documentation on Spring Batch and I found this :

> The 'fail' element instructs a Job to stop with a BatchStatus of FAILED. Unlike the 'end' element, the 'fail' element will not prevent the Job from being restarted. The 'fail' element also allows for an optional 'exit-code' attribute that can be used to customize the ExitStatus of the Job. If no 'exit-code' attribute is given, then the ExitStatus will be "FAILED" by default, to match the BatchStatus.

Follow this links if you want more information :

- [The End Element](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#endElement)
- [The Fail Element](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#failElement)

I hope this will help you !